# Using Modelform with ModelChoicefield does not work for me, gives undefined error when submitting the form

Tags: django, ajax, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to use a form that adds data to the model **RaportProductie** using AJAX.
In the form I have 2 dropdown inputs that take data from the **ManoperaRaportareBloc** model.

These are the attributes from **ManoperaRaportareBloc** : categorie_lucrare and subcategorie_lucrare

When I submit the form it shows an error with undefined.
Please help.
ty.

forms.py:

```
class RaportProductieForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    data = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)   
    categorie_lucrare = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ManoperaRaportareBloc.objects.all().values_list('categorie_lucrare', flat=True))
    subcategorie_lucrare = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ManoperaRaportareBloc.objects.all().values_list('subcategorie_lucrare', flat=True))

    class Meta:
        model = RaportProductie
        fields = ['lucrare', 'data', 'tip', 'subcontractor', 'obiectiv', 'categorie_lucrare', 'subcategorie_lucrare', 'um', 'cantitate', 'valoare_prod']
```

views.py:

```
def raportproductie_create_view(request):
    # request should be ajax and method should be POST.
    if request.is_ajax and request.method == "POST":
        # get the form data
        form = RaportProductieForm(request.POST)
        # save the data and after fetch the object in instance
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            # serialize in new friend object in json
            ser_instance = serializers.serialize('json', [ instance, ])
            # send to client side.
            return JsonResponse({"instance": ser_instance}, status=200)
        else:
            # some form errors occured.
            data = {
                'result': 'error',
                'message': 'Form invalid',
                'form': 'oops.'
            }
            return JsonResponse(data, status=400)

    # some error occured
    return JsonResponse({"error": ""}, status=400)
```

template.html:

```
$("#friend-form").submit(function (e) {
        // preventing from page reload and default actions
        e.preventDefault();
        // serialize the data for sending the form data.
        var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
        console.log(serializedData)
        // make POST ajax call
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "{% url 'proiecte:raportprod-create' %}",
            data: serializedData,
            success: function (response) {             

                // display the newly friend to table.
                var instance = JSON.parse(response["instance"]);
                
                var fields = instance[0]["fields"];                
                
                $("#table-ajax tbody").prepend("<tr><td>"+fields.data+"</td><td>"+fields.tip+"</td><td>"+fields.subcontractor+"</td><td>"+fields.obiectiv+"</td><td>"+fields.categorie_lucrare+"</td><td>"+fields.subcategorie_lucrare+"</td><td>"+fields.um+"</td><td>"+fields.cantitate+"</td><td>"+fields.valoare_prod+"</td></tr>")
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                  var err = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                  alert(err.error);
              }
        })
    })
```

later edit:

i've used pdb to debug, printed the form before checking if valid and it returns this:

```
form.data
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['*********'], 'lucrare': ['1'], 'date': ['2023-01-10'], 'tip': ['1'], 'subcontractor': ['TGC Tadjiki'], 'obiectiv': ['obiectiv'], 'categorie_lucrare': ['CONFECTII_METALICE'], 'subcategorie_lucrare': ['CONSTRUCTIE ATIC - CONF METALICA'], 'um': ['km'], 'cantitate': ['2'], 'valoare_prod': ['0']}>
```

so...the inputs are working,

also in the ajax code, i've also gave a console.log(serializedData) and it outputs this:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=***********=1&date=2023-01-10&tip=1&subcontractor=TGC%20Tadjiki&obiectiv=obiectiv&categorie_lucrare=HIDRO_TERASE&subcategorie_lucrare=CONSTRUCTIE%20ATIC%20-%20CONF%20METALICA&um=mp.&cantitate=2&valoare_prod=0
```

later later edit:

when I am not using ModelChoiceField in the forms.py, and write the inputs by hand, the form submits...

Comment: Why are you setting custom queryset in the model choice fields? Probably, your choices in the request are not matching the valid choices of the fields. I suspect if you try to get the `form.errors` after the `form.is_valid()` is called, you will find the `invalid_choice` errors in your form. My suggestion: remove the custom querysets.

Comment: i used the form.errors, indeed there are `invalid_choice` errors, i'm using the custom queryset because in the form I want to be able to select data that is located in another Model, `ManoperaRaportareBloc`. my model `RaportProductie` where I insert the new data has those attributes as `CharField`, is there a way to transform the selection from `ModelChoiceField` to `CharField`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question, in the `Modelform` modified the custom queryset so that they remain `Charfield` and have added choices:

```
class RaportProductieForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    date = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date.today)
    queryset=ManoperaRaportareBloc.objects.all()
    OPTIONS1 = [(choice.pk, choice.categorie_lucrare) for choice in queryset]
    OPTIONS2 = [(choice.pk, choice.subcategorie_lucrare) for choice in queryset]
    queryset2 = Echipa.objects.all() 
    OPTIONS3 = [(choice.pk, choice.nume) for choice in queryset2]
    
    
    categorie_lucrare = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select( choices = OPTIONS1 ))
    subcategorie_lucrare = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select( choices = OPTIONS2 ))
    subcontractor = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select( choices = OPTIONS3 ))   
    
    class Meta:
        model = RaportProductie
        fields = ['lucrare', 'date', 'tip', 'subcontractor', 'obiectiv', 'categorie_lucrare', 'subcategorie_lucrare', 'um', 'cantitate', 'valoare_prod']
```